# Using SQL to get the SUM of X records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a SQL Server 2019 stored procedure which will allow a user to enter the number of minutes of calls they want to see. If he enters 20 minutes, then I want to show him the first x number of records where the of sum of `call_length = 20` and `< 21` (rounded to the nearest minute) of all of the records.

My code below just selects the records where `call_length` is between 20 and 21. I need the sum of the `call_length` of the records to be between 20 and 21. Thanks

```
DECLARE @Call_Mins int
SET @Call_Mins = 20

SELECT
    reviewid, cumulativesum  
FROM
    (SELECT 
         reviewid, 
         SUM(CONVERT(float,REPLACE(Call_Length,':','.'))) OVER (PARTITION BY ReviewID ORDER BY ReviewID ASC) AS cumulativesum
     FROM 
         LegacyReviews) t 
WHERE
    cumulativesum >= @Call_Mins 
    AND cumulativesum <= @Call_Mins + 1
```

Data looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What data type is `Call-Length`?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: This `REPLACE(Call_Length,':','.')` does not make sense if that first Call_Length `2:30` is 2 hours and 30 minutes as a float that is NOT the same.

Comment: And please provide a [mre] with sample data & desired results

Comment: `SUM(DATEDIFF(second, CAST('00:00:00' AS time), Call_Length)) OVER` would make more sense, then check for `20 * 60 * 60`

Comment: I don't get what you're looking for, what if the call lengths are: 5 min, 10 min, 20 mins. Your code would display zero rows?

Comment: The call_length field is a varchar field stored as mm:ss. There will never be any value over 59:00 (minutes:seconds)

Comment: Storing call_length as a varchar field is not ideal but it gets uploaded into SQL from another application to keep it simple that's why I was doing SUM(CONVERT(float,REPLACE(Call_Length,':','.'))). Let me know if there's a better way

Comment: You would never use float that's for sure. That is for scientific data only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is assuming that your `[Call_Length]` is stored as a Time datatype. (`hh:mm:ss`)

```
DECLARE @Call_Mins AS INT
SET @Call_Mins = 20;

WITH cte as ( 
    SELECT
        [reviewid],
        [Call_Length],
        [RunningTotal] = SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00:00', [Call_Length])) OVER (ORDER BY [reviewid])
    FROM [LegacyReviews])
SELECT
    cte.[reviewid],
    cte.[Call_Length]
FROM cte
WHERE [RunningTotal] < (@Call_Mins + 1) * 60
```

This query uses a Common Table Expression and a running total, that isn't returned per your question, that will not return anything past the first x number of rows that add up to whatever `@Call_Mins` is set to (`+ 1`). This would, in your example, return any values up to `20:59`